# i get this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, opencv, cascade, vision

i try run this program

```
for (x,y,w,h) in jeruks1 and jeruks2:

        cv2.rectangle(img1,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(17,126,234),2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img1,'Jeruk',(x+w,y+h), font, 1, (17,126,234), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) #---write the text

        cv2.rectangle(img2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(17,126,234),2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img2,'Jeruk',(x+w,y+h), font, 1, (17,126,234), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) #---write the text

        roi_gray = cam1[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img1[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        roi_gray = cam2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arizal/Documents/Sorting Jeruk/dual.py", line 54, in <module>
    for (x,y,w,h) in jeruks1 and jeruks2:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

i just try to load 2 cascade.xml on 1 for loop with dual camera
anyone can help me ?

Comment: what is type is `jeruks1` and `jeruks2`?

Answer (score 0):

The word `and` in Python is for taking the logical "and" of two booleans, e.g. `True and False` evaluates to `False`. The error you are receiving is Python saying, *"Hey, I'd like to convert `jeruks1` and `jeruks2` into booleans so that I can take the `and` of them, but I can't do that conversion!"*

You can use the `+` symbol to combine two lists. For example, `[1,5] + [2, 3]` evaluates to `[1,5,2,3]`.